What was the motivation behind the Laplace expansion?
After learning about Cramer's rule, it's clear that the determinant becomes useful for solving systems of equations with a unique solution.
I found that you can derive the formula for a determinant simply by manipulating systems of linear equations and cancelling to solve for a variable, and Cramer's rule just pops out.
I have already done this for a system of 3 equations, I was just wondering if there is an inductive proof that if you use the Laplace expansion to manipulate the equations, you will yield a solution for a variable as in Cramer's rule.
Also, was Laplace motivated by algebraic equations like Cramer, or was he working on something different to arrive at this formula?
Thank you

Check out page 387 in Roman's Advanced Linear Algebra. http://matematicas.uis.edu.co/sites/default/files/paginas/archivos/Advanced%20Linear%20Algebra%20-%20Steven%20Roman.pdf

Corollary 14.24 Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over a field $F$. Let $E=\left(e_1, \ldots, e_n\right)$ be an ordered basis for $V$. Then there is a unique antisymmetric n-linear form $d: V^{\times n} \rightarrow F$ for which
$$
d\left(e_1, \ldots, e_n\right)=1
$$

With this viewpoint, $d$ becomes an antisymmetric $n$-form on the columns of a matrix $A=\left(a_{i, j}\right)$ given by
$$
d(A)=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}(-1)^\sigma a_{1, \sigma(1)} \cdots a_{n, \sigma(n)}
$$
This is called the determinant of the matrix $A$.

So the formula pops out in a unique way which might be the satisfying thing you're looking for. Though I can't speak for how Laplace discovered it.

@random_0620, thank you for your insight, I'll look into that.

Be warned that if you haven't encountered tensor and wedge products before, it might be hard to understand. That being said, the earlier you learn the better!
